# How can I get the updated record in 30 days till today?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a small question about SQL Server: how to get the last 30 days information from this column from **table1**:

| created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-02-05T01:25:42Z | 2020-02-05T01:25:42Z |
| 2020-05-05T02:31:56Z | 2020-05-05T02:31:56Z |

With the above data, I would need something like day count within 30 days.

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
DATEDIFF(CAST(SUBSTR(updated_at,1,10)) AS VARCHAR,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 0 AND 30 ;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE updated_at BETWEEN DATETIME('now', '-30 days') AND DATETIME('now', 'localtime')
```

Would need your expertise to help me with this query

Thank you!

Comment: What is a "day count"?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT otherColumns
        , DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), updated_at) AS updated_at
    FROM table1
) b
WHERE CAST(b.updated_at AS DATE) >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
```

I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want a count of updates by day for 30 (or so) days, then:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, updated_at) as dte, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
WHERE updated_at >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, updated_at)
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, updated_at);
```

Note that SQLite date/time functions (which your code uses) are very peculiar to to SQLite.  So are SQL Server's -- although I personally find them easier to remember.